# Seeing the _users database with CouchDB's Fauxton Browser application

Tags: couchdb, fauxton

Is it possible to see the `_users` database/document with Fauxton (the CouchDB browser client)?

Even logged in as an admin, I'm unable to navigate to the `_users` database where members are stored. Is this a design decision or am I just being dense? Or both?

Comment: usually it is in "databases" like everything else. Perhaps you are using clustering and either looking at the shard layer's fauxton (i.e. 5986) or haven't completed the cluster setup?

Comment: Hmmm. Interesting. I'm not using clustering as the setup tab still gives me the option to cluster; but your comment reminds me of the fact that since CouchDB 2.00, you cannot access certain system tables through the standard 5984 port any longer. Perhaps I'm using the wrong port in the browser. Will try accessing Fauxton through port 5986 later when back in front of stack.

Comment: @lossleader Turns out I could access the `_user` database through port 5986, though I also saw that once I had completed the 'setup wizard' I was then able to see `_users` on 5984 too. If you post an answer with a brief explanation of what the setup wizard is/does; I'll happily mark as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default databases are created by a call to `_cluster_setup` with:

```
  {
    action: 'finish_cluster'
  }
```

Fauxton normally calls [it](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/blob/14b0901df88a909513d8441fcc499023da3524a8/app/addons/setup/setup.actions.js#L40) either when you [select Stand-alone](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-fauxton/blob/14b0901df88a909513d8441fcc499023da3524a8/app/addons/setup/setup.actions.js#L90) or when you finish adding nodes to a cluster and select finalize.

The call triggers [couchdb-setup](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-setup) to create [the default cluster level databases](https://github.com/apache/couchdb-setup/blob/e8d1e32ba3b4f5f3be0e06e5269b12d811f24d52/src/setup.erl#L49):

```
  ["_users", "_replicator", "_global_changes"]
```

Comment: Thanks. As an added note; those who don't finish the cluster setup can still create users (and view the database) via the system 5986 port. When you then go and complete the setup, this database gets wiped and recreated, and access to it via port 5984 begins to work.